# PopupMenu submenu doesn't respect the gravity alignment

Tags: android-layout, android-6.0-marshmallow, popupmenu, layout-gravity, android-gravity

In Android API 23, I have a Popup menu with submenu items. I have defined the gravity to the end, as shown

```
popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, v, Gravity.END);
popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
@Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_add_reminder:
                // Option1
                // ... other options / not relevant for the question    
popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_contact_context);
popupMenu.show();
```

The menu has several submenus, as defined in xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context="es.goodsal.mobile.ContactActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
    android:title="@string/action_add"
    >
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_add_reminder"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add_reminder"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="@string/action_add_reminder"
            />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_add_note"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add_note"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="@string/action_add_note"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_add_opportunity"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add_opportunity"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="@string/action_add_opportunity"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_add_agenda"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add_agenda"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="@string/action_add_agenda"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_add_task"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add_task"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="@string/action_add_task"/>
    </menu>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_contact_edit"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
    android:title="@string/action_edit"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_contact_record"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_contact_default"
    android:title="@string/action_contact"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_report"
    android:title="@string/action_report"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/funnel"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_funnel"
    android:title="@string/action_funnel"
    >
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_funnel_progress"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="@string/action_funnel_progress"
            />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_funnel_regress"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="@string/action_funnel_regress"
            />
    </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

My problem is when the menu is show. The original menu is well aligned to the right (=Gravity.END), but the submenus are aligned to the left, and I don't find a way to define gravity for submenus (and, why is not the same?!?)

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution?

Comment: Sorry, no. We changed the menu logic to have only one level.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but I just released a library for building better nested menus out of my frustrations with PopupMenu: https://github.com/saket/cascade

It's designed to be a drop-in replacement for `PopupMenu`:

```
- val popup = PopupMenu(context, anchor)
+ val popup = CascadePopupMenu(context, anchor)
  popup.inflate(R.menu.nicolas_cage_movies)
  popup.show()
```